# Can't trigger Firebase pub/sub function from HTTPS function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I've created two Firebase functions - one is an HTTPS where I am publishing a message to a topic, and a pub/sub function where I am responding to messages published to that topic.

`testPubSub.ts`

```
import { pubsub } from "firebase-functions";
export const testPubSub = pubsub
  .topic("high-scores")
  .onPublish(async (message, context) => {
    console.log("hit test pubsub");
    return null;
  });
```

`testHttps.ts`

```
import { https } from "firebase-functions";
import { messaging } from "firebase-admin";

export const testHookEndpoint = https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "Test title",
      body: "test body"
    }
  };

  const pubsubResponse = await messaging().sendToTopic("high-scores", payload);
  console.log("response from pubsub", pubsubResponse);
  response.send("success");
});
```

The HTTPS function appears to be running fine (200 response) and messaging is returning a message ID in the response, however I am not seeing the pub/sub function run in the Firebase Console.

When I look at GCP Console I see that "high-scores" has registered as a topic in the Pub/Sub tab, and I'm able to trigger other pub/sub functions in the project through Google Cloud Scheduler.

I'm not sure what step I'm missing for this.

Comment: so everything is working except for the logging in firebase console?

Comment: yeah i'm not getting any errors but that pubsub doesn't appear to running when i look at it either through the firebase console, or through GCP pubsub tab showing activity.

Answer (score 6):

`messaging().sendToTopic("high-scores", payload)` is using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a message to mobile applications subscribed to the given topic.  This is completely different than Cloud Pubsub messaging.  These two products don't actually have anything in common - FCM is for mobile apps and pubsub is for servers.

What you'll need to do instead is use the [node pubsub SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-pub-sub) to send the message to your pubsub topic.